# sending message over a socket using gen_tcp:send/2

Tags: tcp, erlang, erlang-otp, gen-tcp

How to send a message of the form [Integer, String] in erlang using gen_tcp.

Eg: I am looking to send messages of the form [25, "Hello"] or [50, "Hi"] over a socket using gen_tcp:send/2.

I tried to do [ID | Msg] but that doesn't help. 
Thanks

Comment: Here is a nice introduction how to do that: http://learnyousomeerlang.com/buckets-of-sockets Also the official documentation has some examples: http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_tcp.html For more specific answer you will need to post some code example that you tried and it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Erlang, a string is just a list of Integers, so the list `[25, "Hello"]`
is actually represented like `[25, [72,101,108,108,111]]`

The question remains, how to send that information over a Socket in Erlang.

According to the [documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_tcp.html), in Erlang you can send the data as *binary* or as a *list*, which you can set either as `{mode, binary}` or `{mode, list}` when you create the Socket.

In the case that you are working with *binary* data (which is advice since sending and receiving binaries is faster than lists), you can do something like:

```
{ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:connect(Host, Port, [{mode, binary}]).
Data = list_to_binary([25, "Hello"]).
gen_tcp:send(Socket, Data).
```

Now, if you use your socket in *list* mode, you just send the list directly:

```
{ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:connect(Host, Port, [{mode, binary}]).
Data = [25, "Hello"].
gen_tcp:send(Socket, Data).
```

At the server side, if you receive the data in a Socket which is in *list* mode, you convert back to your original format with:

```
[Integer|String] = ListReceived.
```

If you receive the data in a Socket with *binary* mode, then you have to transform the data from a Binary to a List, like:

```
[Integer|String] = binary_to_list(BinaryReceived).
```